# Writing in a file sequential vs in bulk

Tags: java, file-io

I have a program which writes some 8 millions line of data in a flat file. As of now, the program is calling bufferedwriter.write for each of the record and I was planning to write in bulk with the following strategy

1. Keep a data structure (I used array) to hold a specific number of records.
2. write the details in a file using the array. here is the code snippet (array is the name of the Array which stores the record and threshold count is the kick off for writing process)

   ```
   if (array.length==thresholdCount) {
       writeBulk(array);
   }

   public void writeBulk(String[] inpArray) {
        for (String line:inpArray) {
             if (line!=null) {
                  try {
                       writer.write(line +"\n"); 
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                  }
             }
        }

    }
   ```

However I am not seeing much performance improvement. I want to know if there is a way to determine the optimal threshold count?
I was also planning to further tune the code so as to store each element in the array as a concatenation of some n number of records and then call the bulk method. For ex an array with length 5000 will actually contain 50000 records whereby each index in the array contains 10 records. however before doing so, I need the expert opinion.

Comment: Why exactly would you expect a performance improvement given the described scenario ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writes to files are already buffered in a similar fashion before they are pushed to disk (unless you flush -- which actually doesn't always do exactly that either). Thus pre-buffering the writes will not speed up the overall process. Note: that some IO Classes try to do immediate writes by inserting flush requests after each write. For those special cases pre-buffering can sometimes help, but usually you just use a Buffered version of the Class in the first place rather than manually buffer yourself.

If you were writing to somewhere other than the end of the file, then you could see an improvement as writing to the middle of a file wouldn't need to copy the contents of the already flushed entries sitting on your hard-disk.

Comment: thanks for the details.however I do see some performance improvement (in the range of 2 to 5%) when I use different bulk size of 5000,10000 or 20000 and hence was wondering if there is a way to guess some number for bulk writing. The other thing I was planning to do was have a worker thread handing one array of some specified size(which happens to be same as threshold count). This should improve the performance I guess but I am yet to establish that as in my dev environment, writing using thread is slower than sequential writing.

Comment: @user1588737 For large bulks (above 8KB) you might see a minor improvement because it can write more than one block one after another without waiting for the disk to spin. You might also slow it down by having a partial block leftover. You're not going to get dependable speedups from doing so. Pushing the writing task to another thread won't speed up the write to disk process, but generating the string that needs to be written could be done in another thread. This will only improve overall performance if you have something useful for the main thread to do while it waits for the write.